# Rails: has_one association error?

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2

community, I need your help. It's a quite simple problem, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have two models, a Product model and a Condition model. A Product can have only one condition, so I set a one-to-many association between the two. Condition contains fixed records (e.g. good, bad, damaged)

**Product.rb**

```
attr_accessible :condition_id
has_one :condition
```

**Condition.rb**

```
belongs_to :product
```

I have a foreign key condition_id in my products table.
In my products form, I loop through the conditions and set the id:

**_form.html.erb**(Product)

```
<%= f.select :condition_id, Condition.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {} %>
```

I can see that the id is set in the console, when I submit the form. But I can't retrieve the value of the given condition.
In my product show page, I try

```
<%= @product.condition.name %>
```

but it gives me a "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" error. This is also happening when trying in the console.

What am I missing here?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for answering my own question.
It seems that I mixed-matched the association.

So a Product belongs_to :condition and a Condition has_many :products works fine.

However, for me Product has_one :condition and Condition belongs_to :product sounds much more verbose.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and I don't understand the reason why.
The inversion of the association isn't a solution for me, yes it works but it's definitely not verbose in my case. Did you understand why you had to to that ?
Thanks

Comment: No I didn't find out the reason. After consulting the api documentation it still seems weird to me.